# How can I create a method which can work with or without parametrs?

Tags: java

So, I have a method clear() in my CacheManager:

```
@Override
public void clear(String cacheKey) {
    if (cacheKey == null) cache.clear();
    cache.put(cacheKey, null);
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    cache.clear();
}
```

If I get parameters, it clear only 1 element with the same cacheKey, and if I dont get anything it clears whole cache. How can I make it in one method?

I tried making

```
if (cacheKey == null) cache.clear();
```

but anyway it asks for something inside ().

Answer (score 1):

You already have two overloads of your method. The first overload is called for one arguments, the second overload is called for zero arguments.

```
@Override
public void clear(final String cacheKey) {
    cache.put(cacheKey, null);
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    cache.clear();
}

clear("key"); // calls first overload
clear();      // calls second overload
```

If you only want a single overload, you could work around with a varargs method:

```
@Override
public void clear(final String... cacheKeys) {
    if (cacheKeys.length == 0) cache.clear();
    else if (cacheKeys.length == 1) cache.put(cacheKeys[0], null);
    else throw new Exception("Invalid number of cache keys");
}

clear("key"); // clears "key"
clear();      // clears everything
```

Or handle an arbitrary number of keys, with special handling for zero keys; I would *not* recommend this, as this is very surprising:

```
@Override
public void clear(final String... cacheKeys) {
    if (cacheKeys.length == 0) {
        cache.clear();
    } else {
        for (final String key : cacheKeys) {
            cache.put(key, null);
        }
    }
}

clear("key");         // clears "key"
clear("key", "value") // clear "key" and "value"
clear();              // clears everything
```